# is it possible to add click event in certain text of paragraph, which is bind using [innerHTML] using angular4.x?

Tags: angular, event-handling, ionic3, innerhtml

as per h4 tag given below, i am binding html using `innerHTML`. I want particular text inside innerHTML to be clicked and highlighted. i am also sharing pic for better understanding.

```
<h4 class="card-title"  [innerHTML]="highlight()"></h4>
```

https://photos.app.goo.gl/pmjyxWxjmwFfuGiG9

Until now, i have created a directive with @HostListener, with the help of this i am able to check if certain text is available in paragraph and if available i can trigger a event. but i am only able to trigger event, when click on paragraph but i want click to work in element inside `innerHTML`.

Comment: You can wrap the text you want to click and add the click event to that element

Comment: `this.content.replace(new RegExp("justo", "gi"), match => {
            return '<span class="highlightText" #messagecontainer (onclick)="getclick()" >' + match + '</span>';
        });`

with the help of this i check if text is present and then i wrap that text in span but not able to bind click event.

Comment: Sorry for my simple comment. In reality it's a bit more complex. The content of your innerHtml will be interpreted as simple HTML, and all the Angular-specific elements (like bindings) will be ignored. I think you will need an inner Component here to deal with the click event.

Comment: Thanks, I will try.

Comment: Take a look at dynamic components https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

Comment: @Zak Thanks, i solved it by creating component and then bind the click event.

Answer (score 0):

you need use the TAG like Button and change the style

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. i fixed it by creating component and then bind the click event.